# Angular 6 change Internationalization

Tags: angular, regional-settings

I have an application in angular 6, this application is published in a hosting in the US, so it takes thousands as separator "," and some texts appear in English, for example a text for the type of file entry appear in English .
But I need this application to take the configuration for Colombia, where the "." Is used for thousands separator.

And I need the text for the input type file to appear in Spanish, not in English

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" (change)="getFiles($event)">
```

How can I achieve this?

Is there any way to establish a regional configuration in my application, regardless of the configuration of the server where it is installed?

Comment: Do you have another example with the decimal separator? It is not clear what you mean by "a text for the type of file entry" , and you cannot control the language used by the file dialog of native <input type=file> in current browsers.

Comment: Have you ever heard the term `i18n` ? https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: With the miles separator I mean:
in a variable I keep the value of 50000, I have to show it with the miles separator, so it should appear 50,000 with a point, but when I publish my application in the hosting it appears 50,000 with a comma.

As for the <input> I am using this.

When I run it on my computer that has a Colombian-Spanish regional configuration, I see "Seleccione archivo" but when I publish my application in the hosting, "Choose file" appears
For this I need to know if it is possible to configure the language or region .